# Python SQLite insert data into the first record

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, record

I want to add data to the first record in my SQLite Table. Now, when I add new data, it gets added into another record. So, I was wondering how I would be able to do this using python. Both datas will be added at different times. Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the SQL `UPDATE` operation instead of `INSERT`.

Comment: Yes that is what I needed, thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you want to use the update operation. Your SQL statement would be something like

```
UPDATE table SET column = value WHERE condition
```

Comment: What if the data in the column is empty? What would the condition be?

Comment: @Pokechu48 you would use IS NULL as the condition